WebStorm shortcut to navigate to next / previous statements
I have a React component with callback functions and selectors. When I need to navigate next or previous statements it is not possible with Ctrl + Shift + Up / Down arrow as these are constants.
I verified WebStorm shortcut keys and I couldn't find navigate to the next / previous statement shortcut. There is a way to move statements up or down. I'm expecting there might be plugin to get this.

There are Navigate to the Next / Previous Method, but nothing of such for statements (only for moving them).
